# upload multiple template in my online store

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I'm a full stack developer, I want to create an online ecommerce that allow the user to choose a templete and add it to his store and modifie the sections as he likes, I'm stuck at this point, what should I do and from where I can start to create this api

I look on youtube and differents resources but I didn't fine a single one who talked about this topic. so for more detail I'm trying to create an online ecommerece like shopify.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.